# Partial derivatives with max function and module

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x,y)=\max\left\{\frac{x}{9+|y|},\frac{y}{9+|x|}\right\}$$
> The value of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ is:

I started solving it with the definition of partial derivative and arrived at "Non existent", because
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{\frac{y}{9+|x|}-0}{x-0}$$
diverges, put I went to check it on wolfram alpha and [it returned $0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5BMax%5By%2F%289+%2B+Abs%5Bx%5D%29%2C+x%2F%289+%2B+Abs%5By%5D%29%5D%2C+x%5D+at+%280%2C0%29).

Comment: Is there a way to know what wolfram alpha is doing to result a wrong answer?

Answer (score 3):

The limit you are taking above doesn't quite fit the definition of the partial derivative.

Recall that for a function $f$ and a point $(x,y)$, the partial derivative is
$$
f_x(x,y)=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x, y)-f(x,y)}{\Delta x}.
$$
In particular, the partial derivative at $(0,0)$ would be
$$
f_x(0,0)=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{f(\Delta x, 0)-f(0,0)}{\Delta x}.
$$
Now, in our example, we have
$$
f(0,0)=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad f(\Delta x,0)=\max\left\{\frac{\Delta x}{9},0\right\}=\begin{cases}\frac{\Delta x}{9} & \text{if }\Delta x>0\\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.
$$
So, consider the one-sided limits:
$$
\lim_{\Delta x\searrow0}\frac{f(\Delta x,0)-f(0,0)}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x\searrow0}\frac{\frac{\Delta x}{9}}{\Delta x}=\frac{1}{9},
$$
while
$$
\lim_{\Delta x\nearrow 0}\frac{f(\Delta x,0)-f(0,0)}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x\nearrow0}\frac{0-0}{\Delta x}=0.
$$

So, it is true that the partial derivative does not exist.  However, a bit more care should be taken in sticking to the appropriate definition on the way there.

Answer (score 0):

We have $ f(x,0)= \max \{ \frac{x}{9}, 0\}$, hence

$f(x,0)= \frac{x}{9}$ if $x>0$ and $f(x,0)=0$ , if $x<0$.

Therefore

$\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x} =\frac{1}{9}$, if $x>0$ and $\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x} =0$, if $x<0$.

This shows that $ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x}$ does not exist.

Hence $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ does not exist.